# Error in running Torch/Lua, maybe an installation error

Tags: lua, torch

I installed Torch following http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html.

However, when I run things like "th" or any simple code, I got the following error message:

/Users/JianxuChen/torch/install/bin/luajit: ...rs/JianxuChen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:692: attempt to call field 'setheaptracking' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    ...rs/JianxuChen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:692: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ...Chen/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:104: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x01089f8bc0

Does anyone have ever encountered similar issue, or have any idea about how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Torch heap tracking has been introduced quite a while ago (see [this](https://github.com/torch/torch7/commit/a5a4079)) and recently enabled by default on `trepl` (see [this](https://github.com/torch/trepl/commit/516831d)), so this is strange. Is it a fresh install or an update? If you run `pushd ~/torch/pkg/torch/ && git rev-parse HEAD` what do you get?

Comment: @deltheil, I got 
~/torch/pkg/torch ~/torch
840e7312e51e3dd6e28583d4020bfe134eadb9cf

The error is still not solved. Is it possible that some errors occur during installation? The log file (install.log) generated during installation is attached  at : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzY6rRCk_ItCLVctN05TeWE5UlE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So you have a recent enough torch version (which is normal if you cloned torch/distro recently). That said your install log is not complete: it looks like it stopped after `lua-cjson` install (i.e. [here](https://github.com/torch/distro/blob/6fa0c17/install.sh#L79)).

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem and solved it in this way. Your torch is not the latest version. What I do is NOT follow this http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html. Instead download https://github.com/torch/distro and run ./install. Then it works!