# init.lua:692: attempt to call field 'setheaptracking' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, torch

I am installing torch7. After installation, when I run ./th, there is error shown below. Do anyone know how to solve this?

/Lua/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:692: attempt to call field 'setheaptracking' (a nil value)
stack traceback:

```
...de2015.5-/Lua/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:692: in main chunk
[C]: in function 'require'
.../Lua/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:104: in main chunk
[C]: at 0x004064d0
```

Comment: What version of torch did you install? What version of trepl?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259877/error-in-running-torch-lua-maybe-an-installation-error (still unsolved at the time of writing).

Comment: Thanks! I install the latest version. I found the duplicate problem but I did not solve the problem. I am wondering where goes wrong. Here is the log. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B49XSFgf-0yVa09lUWFCZmJpSFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! You are right it is not the latest version. What I do is NOT follow this http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html. Instead download https://github.com/torch/distro and run ./install. Then it works!